# Python code to ID and skip empty rasters failing with numpy array syntax

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, raster

I'm have hundreds of clipped rasters that I need to reclassify using python 2.7.13. When I test approximately 12 of them (including four empty rasters), the script fails on the empty raster due to no data.

I have tried to skip the empty rasters with both arcpy get raster properties and numpy array syntax which I found here.... https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208519/skip-empty-rasters-in-arcgis

```
arcpy.env.workspace = work_dir
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "tif")
for file in rasters:
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    yr_mo = filename[10:17]
    pattern = '*clip*'
    reclass_name = 'Burn_Scar_' + yr_mo + '_' + 'reclass' +'.tif'
## Testing with numpy unique array    
    array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(file)
    values = numpy.unique(array)
    if file.endswith('.tif') and fnmatch.fnmatch(file,pattern):
        if values > 1:
            print values

## Testing with arcpy get raster properties
        file_results = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(file, property_type="MAXIMUM")
        file = file_results.getOutput(0)
        if file_results > 1:
            print file_results

        else:
            outReclass2 = Reclassify(file, "Value", RemapRange([[-2, 0, "NODATA"]]))
            outReclass2.save(reclass_name)
            print(reclass_name)
            print ('skipping....' + file + 'raster is empty')
```

The arcpy code kept printing all maximum values - not just the ones greater than 1.

The numpy.unique(array) errors with 'ValueError' The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). I'm confused what a.any or a.all means & why it was not needed in the other question syntax.

Any other easy ways to skip over empty rasters & only process those with data are appreciated!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Do you understand the cause of the error message?  It says that some test on `array` is producing a boolean array with more than 1 element.  Such an array can't be used in a Python context that expects a scalar boolean.  I suspect we need to see the `traceback` to get a better idea of what/where it's happening.  But also make sure you know what `array` is.  What's its `shape`?  `dtype`?

Comment: In some cases `np.any` or `np.all` works to reduce a boolean array down to a scalar boolean.  But that probably isn't what's needed here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Honesty I really don't understand an array is but I can read up on this and hpaulj you're probably right that I'm using an incorrect thing. I just pulled it from another stack post. I am working with burn fire area raster data which has values of -2 to 366 (-2 to 0 are either water or no data - the other values represent "julian" date. I just want to skip over the rasters with values less than 1. Any suggestions how to do this?   THANKS!!

Comment: The full traceback error is Traceback (most recent call last):File "script name" lline 189 if values > 1: 'ValueError' The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().  Still unsolved :(  Any suggestions?

Comment: `unique` produces an array. What is `values>1` supposed to be testing?  That `if` only accepts a simple true or false not an array of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide sample inputs, I'll demonstrate with my own:

```
In [171]: arr = np.arange(10)                                                          
In [172]: values = np.unique(arr)                                                      
In [173]: values                                                                       
Out[173]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [174]: values>1                                                                     
Out[174]: 
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
In [175]: if np.any(values>1):print(values)                                            
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

If `unique` produces an array with more than 1 element, then `values>1` is a boolean array with multiple values.  That can't be used in a `if` condition.

We can use any/all to reduce the array down to 1 boolean value.  But it isn't obvious what you are trying to do.